# How to assign a Specific Record Type for a Particular User using Permission Set?

Tags: administration, permission-sets, user-management

I'm trying to assign a specific record types for a particular user and i've assigned the Permission Set to that User But i didn't find any changes in the user Side it's Still showing the Savings Record Type.Kindly Help me out and Thanks in Advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbpG5.png)[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU48A.png)

Comment: Do they have access to savings Record Type in their profile?

Comment: Record type settings are cumulative. If they have Savings on their Profile, plus Loan and Fixed Deposit on the Permission Set, they can access all three types.

Comment: Thanks for the response..There are three Record Types Savings,Fixed Deposit and Loan.In Profile Settings I've assigned only Savings Record Type..But i need to assign extra Privileage to the User with Fixed Deposit and Loan Record Types and i need to restrict Savings Record Type for the same User.

Comment: JRiffe Yes the profile  has access to Savings Record Type..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *restrict* permissions by *adding* a permission set to a user. Permissions are "additive", meaning they are all combined together; the most permissive set of permissions for a user determines what capabilities they have. You would have to remove it from the profile and assign it via a different permission set.

Comment: Got it..Thank you.